# GoogleColaboratory$Path Changed

Tags: ubuntu, google-colaboratory

How do I add a path?

!export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

!export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin'

!. /root/.bashrc

output:

/bin/sh: 13: /root/.bashrc: shopt: not found
/bin/sh: 21: /root/.bashrc: shopt: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/local/cuda/bin'
```

Comment: Thank you!
It was added.
It was saved.